# Is it possible to stream to Twilio video API via RTMP or RTP

Tags: webrtc, twilio, rtmp, rtp, twilio-api

Is it possible to stream to Twilio Video API from desktop applications like XSplit broadcaster or OBS (via RTMP or RTP protocols)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Twilio Video uses WebRTC, so you would need to convert your RTMP or RTP stream into WebRTC somehow. I'm afraid that's all I know though. There's some [interesting articles online about that conversion](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1106023/Migration-of-a-streaming-service-from-RTMP-to-WebR) but not covering Twilio Video. It's probably a good start though.

Comment: Has this changed yet?  I’m interested in broadcasting video to large numbers of people. Currently using OpenTok.

Comment: @MattLally This has not changed, no. Twilio Video is primarily for 1:1, collaboration or small groups (up to 50) and you need another solution if you want to stream one to many.

Comment: Thanks @philnash!